# create json from object with root element in groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have the following class:

```
 class Foo {
    int a
    String b
 }
```

When I convert from object to string using json builder:

```
 new JsonBuilder(foo).toPrettyString()
```

json string will be like:

```
{a:"", b: ""}
```

But I need:

```
{ foo { a:"", b:""}}
```

How do I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

class Foo {
 int a
 String b
}

def f = new Foo(a:1, b:"2")

new JsonBuilder(foo:f).toPrettyString()
```

Comment: Thx Working. Im an newbee. :)